# Read rows from a text file and sort the values from rows by mean (average) by writing them in a new text file

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, text-files, java-stream

I have a text file, which contains the following text:

Input.txt:

```
name s1 s2 s3 s4 
Jack 2 4 6 5  
Alex 3 5 5 5 
Brian 6 6 4 5
```

Now the highest average is for Brian: 5.2; Alex: 4.5; Jack: 4.25.
My task is to get the average number for each Person and then sort people by ascending average score, then create a new text file with the sorted values.

The above example must look like this in the new text file.

Output.txt:

```
name s1 s2 s3 s4
Brian 6 6 4 5
Alex 3 5 5 5
Jack 2 4 6 5
```

So far I came up with 2 solutions, none of which can make the task to its end.

The first one is:

```
public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int sortKeyIndex = 0;

        Path inputFile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample.txt");
        Path outputFile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\new-sample.txt");

        String separator = " ";
        Stream<CharSequence> sortedLines =
        Files.lines(inputFile)
             .skip(1)
             .map(sorting -> sorting.split(separator))
             .sorted(Comparator.comparing(sorting -> sorting[sortKeyIndex]))
             .map(sorting -> String.join(separator, sorting));

        Files.write(outputFile, sortedLines::iterator, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);  
    }
}
```

The second one is:

```
public class SortTestSecond {
    private static BufferedReader theReader;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            theReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test2.txt"));
            theReader.readLine();
            String currLine = null;

            while((currLine = theReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(currLine);
                StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(currLine, " ");
                int theCount=strTok.countTokens();
                int theArray[]=new int[theCount];
                int i = 0;

                while(strTok.hasMoreTokens() && i != theCount) {
                    theArray[i]=Integer.valueOf(strTok.nextToken());
                    i = i + 1;
                }

                int theSum = 0;
                for(int j =0;j < theArray.length; j++) {
                    theSum = theSum + theArray[j];
                }

                float average = (float) theSum / theArray.length;
                System.out.println("Average: " + average);
            }
        } catch(IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            theReader.close();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to add the results of running each solution? Thanks

Comment: The wrong indentation makes the code unreadable. Please reformat your code.

Comment: @JohnM Well i can sort them alphabetically and I can sort them by the first number, but I don't know how to find the average for each row of numbers and then sort the students like in the Output.txt which i provided.

Comment: @vanje sorry I don't know if I did it, because I am new here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One variant would be

```
Path inputFile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample.txt");
Path outputFile = inputFile.resolveSibling("new-sample.txt");

String separator = " ", newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(separator);
try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(inputFile);
    BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {

    bw.append(br.readLine()).append(newLine); // header
    br.lines()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(line ->
          -p.splitAsStream(line).skip(1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).average().orElse(-1)))
      .forEachOrdered(s -> {
        try { bw.append(s).append(newLine); }
        catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    });
}
```

However, the sorting operation requires the data in memory anyway, even if it looks like fluent streaming, it’s just hidden here. If we accept the fact that we will have the entire data in memory, we can simplify the entire operation as:

```
Path inputFile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sample.txt");
Path outputFile = inputFile.resolveSibling("new-sample.txt");

String separator = " ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(separator);

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(inputFile);
lines.subList(1, lines.size())
     .sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(line ->
         -p.splitAsStream(line).skip(1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).average().orElse(-1)));
Files.write(outputFile, lines, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

Comment: @RavindraRanwala in the first variant, the statement `bw.append(br.readLine()).append(newLine);` reads and write the first line, before acquiring the stream from the `BufferedReader`. That way, the stream operation doesn’t have to deal with the header at all. In the second variant, the sorting is only applied to `.subList(1, lines.size())`, so the first line isn’t touched and stays at the beginning of the list.

Comment: second approach seems more intuitive. Can we get the first line using streams approach. And we may have to close the resources in 2nd approach as well.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala treating a single element specially in a stream operation is somewhere between hard and impossible. That’s why fetching the header from a `BufferedReader` before the stream operation is the best option. In the second variant, `Files.readAllLines` and `Files.write` do open and close the resources within the operation, so there’s nothing more to do.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a class called Candidate which implements Comparable

```
    class Candidate implements Comparable {
        String name;
        int [] values;
        float average;
    }

    Candidate(String Name, int [] values) {
       this.name = Name;
       this.values = values;
       this.average = getAverage();
    }
    public float getAverage() {
         int sum = 0;
         for(int c : values) {
           sum += c;
          }
         return (float) sum/values.length;
    }
    @override
    public int compareTo(Candidate c) {
           if(c.average>this.average){
               return 1;
           } else {
               return -1;
             }
    }
}
```

Coming to your main class you need to create an object for each line and populate with the constructor.

```
class main {

   HashMap<String, Candidate> candidateList = new HashMap<String, Candidate>();
   public static void main(String args[]) {

        String FILENAME = "E:\\test\\filename.txt";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
          fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
          br = new BufferedReader(fr);

          String sCurrentLine;

          while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
             String [] currentLine = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
             String name = currentLine[0];
             int [] values = new int[currentLine.length-1];
             for(int i=1; i<currentLine.length; i++) {
                 values[i-1] = Integer.valueOf(currentLine[i]);
             }
                Candidate c = new Candidate(name,values);
                candidateList.put(name,c);// file converted to a list of candidates 
           }

   }

}
```

Sort that file and print it to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. Firstly read each line of file and then map it to a `Person` class. Then sort each `Person` based on the sum of four values, since it ramifies the average order. Finally collect the sorted objects as a `String`. The last is to write that `String` representation of sorted `Person` objects into a file. Also it's worth using Java 8 for this.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\data\\sample.txt"))) {
    final String sortedPeople = stream.skip(1).map(l -> l.split(" "))
            .map(a -> new Person(a[0], Integer.parseInt(a[1]), Integer.parseInt(a[2]), Integer.parseInt(a[3]),
                    Integer.parseInt(a[4])))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::sum).reversed()).map(Person::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    System.out.println(sortedPeople);

    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\data\\new-sample.txt");
    byte[] strToBytes = sortedPeople.getBytes();

    Files.write(path, strToBytes);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int valOne;
    private final int valTwo;
    private final int valThree;
    private final int valFour;

    public Person(String name, int valOne, int valTwo, int valThree, int valFour) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.valOne = valOne;
        this.valTwo = valTwo;
        this.valThree = valThree;
        this.valFour = valFour;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValOne() {
        return valOne;
    }

    public int getValTwo() {
        return valTwo;
    }

    public int getValThree() {
        return valThree;
    }

    public int getValFour() {
        return valFour;
    }

    public int sum() {
        return this.valOne + this.valTwo + this.valThree + this.valFour;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + valOne + ", " + valTwo + ", " + valThree + ", " + valFour;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Brian, 6, 6, 4, 5
Alex, 3, 5, 5, 5
Jack, 2, 4, 6, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
package com.grsdev.stackoverflow.question180629.pack01;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ScoreTransformer {

    private final static String INPUT_FILE="input.txt";

    private final static String OUTPUT_FILE="output.txt";

    private final static String SEPARATOR=" ";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        Path inputPath=Paths.get(INPUT_FILE));

        Stream<String> sorted= Files
             .lines(inputPath)
             .skip(1)
             .map(t->PersonConvertor.parseStringToPerson(t, SEPARATOR))
             .sorted((p1,p2)->(int)(p2.getAverageScore()-p1.getAverageScore()))
             .map(p->PersonConvertor.convertToString(p, SEPARATOR));

        Files.write(Paths.get(OUTPUT_FILE), sorted.collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }

}

class PersonConvertor {

    public static Person parseStringToPerson(String line,String separator) {

        Person blankPerson = new  Person(null, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        if(line==null) return blankPerson;

        String[] array = line.split(separator);

        if(array.length==5) {
            return new Person (array[0],Integer.parseInt(array[1]),Integer.parseInt(array[2]),Integer.parseInt(array[3]),Integer.parseInt(array[4]));
        }

        return blankPerson;
    }

    public static String convertToString(Person p,String separator) {

        if(p==null)return "";

        String line=p.getName()+separator+p.getScore1()+separator+p.getScore2()+ separator+p.getScore3()+separator+p.getScore4();
        return line;
    }

}


class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private String name;

    private int score1,score2,score3,score4;

    private float averageScore;

    public Person(String name, int score1, int score2, int score3, int score4) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.score1 = score1;
        this.score2 = score2;
        this.score3 = score3;
        this.score4 = score4;

        setAverageScore(((getScore1()+getScore2()+getScore3()+getScore4())/4));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore1() {
        return score1;
    }

    public void setScore1(int score1) {
        this.score1 = score1;
    }

    public int getScore2() {
        return score2;
    }

    public void setScore2(int score2) {
        this.score2 = score2;
    }

    public int getScore3() {
        return score3;
    }

    public void setScore3(int score3) {
        this.score3 = score3;
    }

    public int getScore4() {
        return score4;
    }

    public void setScore4(int score4) {
        this.score4 = score4;
    }

    public float getAverageScore() {
        return averageScore;
    }

    public void setAverageScore(float averageScore) {
        this.averageScore = averageScore;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return (int) (this.averageScore-p.getAverageScore());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person name=" + name + ", score1=" + score1 + ", score2=" + score2 + ", score3=" + score3 + ", score4="
                + score4 + ", averageScore=" + averageScore + "]";
    }



}
```